# Export SVG with external CSS to server

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, base64

I am using d3.js library to generate a chart on client side based on some parameters. Generated chart has some styling applied based on external css file. Is it possible to export that chart with same styling to server? I tried exporting the chart using base64 data but I get chart without any styling being applied.
 Any help is highly appreciated!

jsfiddle

P.S. Output shown in JsFiddle is my how my UI looks now.
But for generating PDF I send base64 data back to server which doesn't include stylings.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tyx6nuw1/

Comment: I am afraid unless you inline css into SVG there is no way to “get” this style data. But would be positively surprised if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to export a SVG, it's essential to have the styles inline. But if you're looking for a workaround for the styles already coming in from an external CSS file, here's an approach to do that.

[DEMO IMPLEMENTING EXPORTING OF SVG WITH EXTERNAL CSS STYLING](https://jsfiddle.net/tyx6nuw1/25/)

In the code, the `function` named **addInlineStyling** receives a list of elements and the associated properties, extracts styles/property values using `Window.getComputedStyles` method and assigns to the element respectively.

**Relevant code:**

```
function addInlineStyling(elements) {
  if(elements && elements.length) {
    elements.forEach(function(d) {
     d3.selectAll(d.el).each(function(){
      var element = this;
      if(d.properties && d.properties.length) {
        d.properties.forEach(function(prop) {
          var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element, null),
            value = computedStyle.getPropertyValue(prop);
          element.style[prop] = value;
        });
      }
    });
   });
  }
}
```

Feel free to modify the way the array is being sent and used to extract styles but I wanted to let you know that this is one approach to doing that. *ALTHOUGH IT'S ADVISABLE TO HAVE INLINE STYLING.*

And please add the missing styles (if any).

Here's the exported image: 
[image]

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much :)

Comment: here we are getting base64 string in svg+xml format. Is it also possible to get in png or jpg format?

Comment: Yes, it is by using a canvas to draw this image and exporting the canvas to either png or jpg. Refer [this](http://bl.ocks.org/Rokotyan/0556f8facbaf344507cdc45dc3622177) and you can replace `canvas.toBlob` with `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')`. If you're unable to do that, create a new question and tag me in.